# Best way to run remote commands thru ssh in Twisted?

Tags: python, ssh, twisted

I have a twisted application which now needs to monitor processes running on several boxes. The way I manually do is 'ssh and ps', now I'd like my twisted application to do. I have 2 options.

Use `paramiko` or leverage the power of `twisted.conch`

I really want to use `twisted.conch` but my research led me to believe that its primarily intended to create SSHServers and SSHClients. However my requirement is a simple `remoteExecute(some_cmd)`

I was able to figure out how to do this using `paramiko` but I didnt want to stick`paramiko` in my twisted app before looking at how to do this using `twisted.conch`

Code snippets using `twisted` on how to run `remote_cmds` using ssh would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Followup - Happily, the ticket I referenced below is now resolved.  The simpler API will be included in the next release of Twisted.  The original answer is still a valid way to use Conch and may reveal some interesting details about what's going on, but from Twisted 13.1 and on, if you just want to run a command and handle it's I/O, [this simpler interface will work](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/conch/howto/listings/echoclient_ssh.py?rev=38381).

---

It takes an unfortunately large amount of code to execute a command on an SSH using the Conch client APIs.  Conch makes you deal with a lot of different layers, even if you just want sensible boring default behavior.  However, it's certainly possible.  Here's some code which I've been meaning to finish and add to Twisted to simplify this case:

```
import sys, os

from zope.interface import implements

from twisted.python.failure import Failure
from twisted.python.log import err
from twisted.internet.error import ConnectionDone
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, succeed, setDebugging
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IStreamClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

from twisted.conch.ssh.common import NS
from twisted.conch.ssh.channel import SSHChannel
from twisted.conch.ssh.transport import SSHClientTransport
from twisted.conch.ssh.connection import SSHConnection
from twisted.conch.client.default import SSHUserAuthClient
from twisted.conch.client.options import ConchOptions

# setDebugging(True)


class _CommandTransport(SSHClientTransport):
    _secured = False

    def verifyHostKey(self, hostKey, fingerprint):
        return succeed(True)


    def connectionSecure(self):
        self._secured = True
        command = _CommandConnection(
            self.factory.command,
            self.factory.commandProtocolFactory,
            self.factory.commandConnected)
        userauth = SSHUserAuthClient(
            os.environ['USER'], ConchOptions(), command)
        self.requestService(userauth)


    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if not self._secured:
            self.factory.commandConnected.errback(reason)



class _CommandConnection(SSHConnection):
    def __init__(self, command, protocolFactory, commandConnected):
        SSHConnection.__init__(self)
        self._command = command
        self._protocolFactory = protocolFactory
        self._commandConnected = commandConnected


    def serviceStarted(self):
        channel = _CommandChannel(
            self._command, self._protocolFactory, self._commandConnected)
        self.openChannel(channel)



class _CommandChannel(SSHChannel):
    name = 'session'

    def __init__(self, command, protocolFactory, commandConnected):
        SSHChannel.__init__(self)
        self._command = command
        self._protocolFactory = protocolFactory
        self._commandConnected = commandConnected


    def openFailed(self, reason):
        self._commandConnected.errback(reason)


    def channelOpen(self, ignored):
        self.conn.sendRequest(self, 'exec', NS(self._command))
        self._protocol = self._protocolFactory.buildProtocol(None)
        self._protocol.makeConnection(self)


    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        self._protocol.dataReceived(bytes)


    def closed(self):
        self._protocol.connectionLost(
            Failure(ConnectionDone("ssh channel closed")))



class SSHCommandClientEndpoint(object):
    implements(IStreamClientEndpoint)

    def __init__(self, command, sshServer):
        self._command = command
        self._sshServer = sshServer


    def connect(self, protocolFactory):
        factory = Factory()
        factory.protocol = _CommandTransport
        factory.command = self._command
        factory.commandProtocolFactory = protocolFactory
        factory.commandConnected = Deferred()

        d = self._sshServer.connect(factory)
        d.addErrback(factory.commandConnected.errback)

        return factory.commandConnected



class StdoutEcho(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        sys.stdout.write(bytes)
        sys.stdout.flush()


    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.finished.callback(None)



def copyToStdout(endpoint):
    echoFactory = Factory()
    echoFactory.protocol = StdoutEcho
    echoFactory.finished = Deferred()
    d = endpoint.connect(echoFactory)
    d.addErrback(echoFactory.finished.errback)
    return echoFactory.finished



def main():
    from twisted.python.log import startLogging
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint

    # startLogging(sys.stdout)

    sshServer = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 22)
    commandEndpoint = SSHCommandClientEndpoint("/bin/ls", sshServer)

    d = copyToStdout(commandEndpoint)
    d.addErrback(err, "ssh command / copy to stdout failed")
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some things to note about it:

- It uses the new endpoint APIs introduced in Twisted 10.1.  It's possible to do this directly on `reactor.connectTCP`, but I did it as an endpoint to make it more useful; endpoints can be swapped easily without the code that actually asks for a connection knowing.
- It does no host key verification at all!  `_CommandTransport.verifyHostKey` is where you would implement that.  Take a look at `twisted/conch/client/default.py` for some hints about what kinds of things you might want to do.
- It takes `$USER` to be the remote username, which you may want to be a parameter.
- It probably only works with key authentication.  If you want to enable password authentication, you probably need to subclass `SSHUserAuthClient` and override `getPassword` to do something.
- Almost all of the layers of SSH and Conch are visible here:

  - `_CommandTransport` is at the bottom, a plain old protocol that implements the SSH transport protocol.  It creates a...
  - `_CommandConnection` which implements the SSH connection negotiation parts of the protocol.  Once that completes, a...
  - `_CommandChannel` is used to talk to a newly opened SSH channel.  `_CommandChannel` does the actual exec to launch your command.  Once the channel is opened it creates an instance of...
  - `StdoutEcho`, or whatever other protocol you supply.  This protocol will get the output from the command you execute, and can write to the command's stdin.

See http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4698 for progress in Twisted on supporting this with less code.

Comment: Thanks a lot exarkun! It struck me really odd because, as you rightly mentioned, there should be simple, out-of-box solution of this trivial thing. Glad that there's already work in that direction. Thanks again for the prompt response.