# "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" when running ssh through python without paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, stdin

I am running ssh from within Python without the use of an external library like Paramiko. I have my reasons for doing it this way instead of through an external library.

Basically I am doing `subprocess.Popen("ssh -t bla -- command")`

I get the following message when doing this:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

The reason I am running it with `-t` is I want the remote command to terminate when I kill my python script.

When I try with `-t -t` (to force it), I get the following message:

```
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Is there a way I can run my ssh command with `-t` through Python?

Comment: If you can muck about with remote sshd settings, this should help: http://superuser.com/questions/396994/setting-ssh-to-terminate-remote-process-upon-disconnection

Answer (score 2):

May I respectfully suggest that you are asking the wrong question, and that the right question might be something like "how do I make sure a sub process terminates when my python program terminates"

You could do some clever unix stuff like allocate a pty and make sure that you sub process uses this as std in out etc. so that the ssh command thinks that it's talking to a terminal rather than a pipe, but this is probably not what you really want to do.

Comment: The ssh subprocess does terminate when I kill my python script. However, the command that it initiated on the remote host does not terminate unless I pass in -t flag to the ssh command.
But when I pass in the -t flag to ssh, it doesn't respect that flag and gives me the error message I pasted in the question body.

Comment: Then It's the other process that I think you should be looking at.why doesn't it exit properly when the remote ssh gets dropped.sounds like it's ignoring a signal that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

To terminate the remote command when the python script gets killed, you may (as an alternative to the `-t` option to `ssh`) implement a workaround that uses a named pipe to convert "EOF to SIGHUP" when the stdin of `sshd` is being closed (see [Bug 396 - sshd orphans processes when no pty allocated](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396#c14)).

```
# sample code in Bash

# press ctrl-d for EOF
ssh localhost '
TUBE=/tmp/myfifo.fifo
rm -f "$TUBE"
mkfifo "$TUBE"
#exec 3<>"$TUBE"

<"$TUBE" sleep 100 &  appPID=$!

# cf. "OpenSSH and non-blocking mode", 
# http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2005-July/023090.html
#cat >"$TUBE"
#socat -u STDIN "PIPE:$TUBE"
dd of="$TUBE" bs=1 2>/dev/null
#while IFS="" read -r -n 1 char; do printf '%s' "$char"; done > "$TUBE"

#kill -HUP -$appPID 
kill $appPID

rm -f "$TUBE"
'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're really asking for the inverse of the old *nohup* command; that is to say some way to ensure that the remote command responds to the HUP (hang-up) signal that's generated by the TTY (PTY or psuedo-tty) driver when the underlying connection to it is closed.

Personally I suspect that [Paramiko](https://github.com/robey/paramiko) is going to be far better than trying to manage this with the *subprocess* module.  You can have Paramiko open the connection, allocate the pty and execute your commands without any cruft; and the code to use your existing *known_hosts* and identity files (private keys) is relatively straightforward.

This recipe [Copy files over SSH using paramiko](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576810/)  at ActiveState shows the basics of loading ssh known_hosts, using identity files and interacting with any *ssh agent* you might be running.  From there what you're asking for should simply be a matter of:

- [creating a session](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#connect),
- [creating a channel](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#open_channel),
- [getting a pty](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#get_pty)
- and [executing your remote command](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#exec_command) **or** [invoking a shell](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#invoke_shell) and sending the your command to that shell using the *stdin* file like object it returns.

You could also use the [TwistedConch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch) implementation of the SSH protocols.  However, wrapping your head around the Twisted programming framework might be rather more difficult.

Here's an example of a simple ssh server in Twisted, with pty support: [Twisted Conch in 60 Seconds: PTY Requests](http://as.ynchrono.us/2011/04/twisted-conch-in-60-seconds-pty.html)
Here's an SO thread from only a week before yours was posted [Best way to run remote commands thru ssh in Twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617507/best-way-to-run-remote-commands-thru-ssh-in-twisted) but that didn't cover pty related issues at all.  Looking at the docs for [twisted.conch.ssh.session](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/9.0.0/api/twisted.conch.ssh.session.SSHSession.html) suggests that it has pty support; but lists it as "Undocumented."

Of course you could even go with [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect), spawn a shell to your local *ssh* client and send your remote command through that.  This would most closely emulate the way that you'd run the command from your own shell.