# How to wrap a call of an interactive ssh session from inside a Python script?

Tags: python, ssh

I am writing a SSH command line wrapper but I discovered that doesn't want to run interactively.

Let's say I do have `ssh.py` which is supposed to establish an interactive `ssh` session.

If I run:

- `subprocess.open('ssh -t server')` and `p.wait()`, I will get an error: 
  `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`
- if I try to force it by using `-t -t` it will block.

Note: I really need an interactive session, as I try to use `screen` to restore a previous connection.

How can I solve this problem?

Note: I do not want to control the called ssh from python in any way.

Comment: Have you seen the answers to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664002/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal-when-run

Comment: @jedwards now I did, still the other one doesn't provide an answer to the problem.

Comment: Should I reimplement my wrapper in `bash`? I do not have the same problem if I call `bash`. Still, I would prefer to use python, because doing the same logic in bash would be... really ugly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I do not want to control the called ssh from Python in any way"?  Is it ok to spawn ssh with your underlying OS, but look at ssh's prompts in python?

Comment: So you basically want a terminal emulator for Python?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I am looking for a one-file solution so using external libraries. In fact the question should have nothing to do with SSH, it should also apply for the case you want to run an interactive console application locally too.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as I'm implementing a secrets manager.
On ubuntu:

```
     os.execlp('ssh', f'-l {user}', f'{host}')
```

This solution works on ubuntu and I assume other linux distro's.

It does not work on macos.

Comment: kkron, please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This is not a me to answer.  My answer works on linux.  I reworded it to clarify that fact.

Comment: Wasn't a me to answer.  It was a this works for you if you're on linux but it's not very portable.